# React-Native: Keyboard runs slow when even on real device

Tags: react-native

Every time my app runs the keyborad seems to run slower than expected, i have a recursive call that updates an alert every 500 milli-seconds but is this why the keyboard is running slow when typing or is this a seperate issue. I dont have code to show you as everything else in the app runs fast apart from the keyboard. I have js dev mode disabled aswel.

Any clues?

```
<AutoGrowingTextInput underlineColorAndroid="transparent" style={{flex:1}}

                              maxHeight={200}
                                         minHeight={45}
                             placeholder="Message..."
                             style={{backgroundColor:'#ffffff',}}
                             onChangeText={(message) => this.setState({message})}
                             value={this.state.message}
                           />


getLatestMessagesRecurse = () =>{
    return fetch('http://example.com/example.php', {
                          method: 'POST',
                          headers: {
                            Accept: 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          },
                          body: JSON.stringify({
                            example: example,
                            example: example
                          }),
                        }).then((response) => response.json())
                            .then((responseJson) => {
                                if(responseJson != false){
                                this.setState({_messageAlert: true});
                                }else{

                                this.setState({_messageAlert: false});
                                }
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                alert(error);
                            });
}

    componentDidMount() {
  this._interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.recurse();
  }, 500);
}

recurse = () => {
    this.getLatestMessagesRecurse();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this._interval);
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the code for your recursive call that updates the alert.

Comment: @diogenesgg, i have updated

Comment: i set the recurse to 5 seconds and still no luck